# Having this stripe issue after updating Xcode ^

Tags: flutter

I updated my MacBook and now I get this issue from Xcode about my project and can run it :

```
/Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:51:81:
    error: 'new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin
                                                    deserializer:[STPIssuingCardPin new]
                                                                                    ^
    In file included from
    /Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:11:
    /Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/PublicHeaders/STPIssuingCardPin.h:22:
    1: note: 'init' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    - (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin")));
    ^
    /Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:101:81:
    error: 'new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin
                                                    deserializer:[STPIssuingCardPin new]
                                                                                    ^
    In file included from
    /Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:11:
    /Users/ralucaraluca/Downloads/tariffo/tariffo/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/PublicHeaders/STPIssuingCardPin.h:22:
    1: note: 'init' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    - (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin")));

    ^
```

ANY IDEA WHAT CAN I DO???

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's actually a problem caused by updating the XCode.

There are some workarounds in [here](https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues/284). One of them is the XCode downgrade :/

Comment: My temporary workaround is gonna be using Android for development for now, until the fix comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me, I changed my macbook and now xcode is giving this weird issue. I followed this link and updated my 'Stripe' version.

['new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274177/new-is-unavailable-you-cannot-directly-instantiate-an-stpissuingcardpin)

This is what i followed:

- comment out pod 'stripe' line
- run pod install
- uncomment line
- run pod install