# How to fix Stripe payment issue with Xcode 12.5 in flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, stripe-payments

I have a flutter app that uses Stripe payment dependency 1.0.11 in flutter v1.22.6. It was working before but after ugraded my macOS to BigSur and also updated Xcode 12.5.1 and re running to iOS Simulator I got 2 errors. Can anyone help me fix this ?

```
    Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:51:81: error: 'new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin
                                                    deserializer:[STPIssuingCardPin new]
                                                                                    ^
    In file included from /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:11:
    /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/PublicHeaders/STPIssuingCardPin.h:22:1: note: 'init' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    - (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin")));
    ^
    /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:101:81: error: 'new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin
                                                    deserializer:[STPIssuingCardPin new]
                                                                                    ^
    In file included from /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/STPPinManagementService.m:11:
    /Users/kk54/Desktop/Tools/goers/goers-flutter/ios/Pods/Stripe/Stripe/PublicHeaders/STPIssuingCardPin.h:22:1: note: 'init' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    - (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin")));
    ^
    2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['new' is unavailable: You cannot directly instantiate an STPIssuingCardPin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274177/new-is-unavailable-you-cannot-directly-instantiate-an-stpissuingcardpin)

Comment: This question could use a [repro]. Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known compatibility issue with Xcode 12.5: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/pull/1766

The solution is upgrading the Stripe pod to 21.3.1 or above.
Other alternative solutions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67284560/3631795